# tmuxinator unknown command: C-m

Tags: zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

I want to write a single script to tunnel multiple ip and port to my local ports using tsh. I came across tmux and tmuxinator to do the job.
I have written a tmuxinator project as

```
# ./.tmuxinator.yml

name: tunnels
root: ~/

windows:
  - myTunnels:
      panes:
        - tunnelHostOne:
          - echo "HostOne"
          - echo "tsh ssh --proxy=someProxy.com -L 127.0.0.1:5443:host1-dns.com:5432 codetalker@node1";
          - tsh ssh --proxy=someProxy.com -L 127.0.0.1:5443:host1-dns.com:5432 codetalker@node1;
        - tunnelCostDb:
          - echo "HostTwo"
          - echo "tsh ssh --proxy=someProxy.com -L 127.0.0.1:5445:host2-dns.com:5432 codetalker@node2";
          - tsh ssh --proxy=someProxy.com -L 127.0.0.1:5445:host2-dns.com:5432 codetalker@node2;
```

but when I run this project using

```
tmuxinator tunnels
```

It opens up a window with two panes as expected and only first echo command is run in both the panes and on detaching the terminal contains the output as

```
unknown command: C-m
unknown command: C-m
unknown command: C-m
unknown command: C-m
[detached (from session tunnels)]
```

I can understand that `C-m` should be `Enter` to execute the commands and move to other but I have no idea how to fix it. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with tmuxinator 3.0.5 on an old mac. The problem was that I had unnecessary semicolons (;) at the end of some pane lines. By removing them, all was ok.

You can reproduce the problem with the following sample. Remove the semicolons and all is good.

```
# /home/X00000X/.config/tmuxinator/semicolon-test.yml

name: semicolon-test
root: ~

windows:
  - devops:
      panes:
        - echo test;
        - echo test;
#                  ^ these are the problem, by removing them, it works ok.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).